# Why can't I add t4g instances to my EKS cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EKS cluster with a nodegroup consisting of a couple of t3.small EC2 instances.

I want to switch to t4g.micro instances (double the amount of instances) because it will be cheaper.
My approach was that I'll add a new nodegroup, consisting of t4g.micro instances and once they're up I'll just delete the t3.small nodegroup, but for some reason when I'm creating the new node group it doesn't let me choose t4g instance types.

I did chose the Amazon Linux 2 ARM type when creating the new node group but it still only allowed me to choose m6g and r6g instance types but not t4g.

Any ideas?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65312511

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after not getting a single response in almost two weeks, I paid for a premium AWS Support Plan to help me.

Turns out there are some instance types at the time of writing this that are not available on the EKS Console. The solution is to create the node group using a command line tool like [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) or [eksctl](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started-eksctl.html).

Here is the [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) command:

```
aws eks create-nodegroup --cluster-name my-cluster-name --nodegroup-name my-nodegroup-name --subnets subnet-0xxxxxxx --instance-types t4g.micro --ami-type AL2_ARM_64 --remote-access ec2SshKey=mySshKeyPair --node-role arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:role/my-iam-name
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! In my case I was getting `[t4g.xlarge] is not a valid instance type for requested amiType AL2_x86_64`, which was due to the fact I had not explicitly set the ami type to `AL2_ARM_64`